# useSelector doesnt update the variable to its latest value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, razorpay

I have used redux to maintain state of order and fetching order_id from it...I have a button that triggers this handleCheckout() function which dispatches new state of order_id. Then on payment success this payment_success() function is called and it prints the old value not the new value even though the order_id has changed. What could be the issue and what could possibly be the solution?

```
function CartList({ carts, total }) {
  var dispatch = useDispatch();

  var { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  var { order_id } = useSelector((state) => state.order);

  function payment_success(payload) {
    // console.log(payload);
    // verifyPayment(payload, order_id);
    console.log(order_id);
  }

  function payment_failed() {
    console.log("Payment Failed");
  }

  function handleCheckout() {
    getOrderId(carts[0].ProductId).then(async (data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      dispatch(createOrder(data));
      var options = {
        ...data,
        handler: payment_success,
        prefill: {
          email: "test@test.com",
          contact: 8900000000,
          name: user.name,
        },
      };
      var rpay = new window.Razorpay(options);
      rpay.open();
      rpay.on("payment.failed", payment_failed);
    });
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div style={{ margin: "50px 40px" }}>
        <h3>My Cart</h3>
        {carts.map((cart) => (
          <CartItem {...cart} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <Container>
        <Row className="justify-content-center">
          <Col md="3" className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <p>Total: {total}</p>
            <Button onClick={handleCheckout} variant="primary">
              Order Now
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't know why redux state is not updated in `payment_success` but you could always try to use `localStorage`. Close to the dispatch you call `localStorage.setItem` storing `data` in cache and then in `payment_success` call `localStorage.getItem`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a stale closure over the `user` variable from the last render there. That variable will never be updated - `useSelector` triggers a component update and in the next render, there will be a new `user` variable with the correct content - but your `payment_success` closure still points at the old `user` variable.

Comment: I am also having similar problem. How to fix it.
how to pass updated order_id to ```payment_success``` closure

Comment: You would need to return the important info from your thunk (`const result = await dispatch(thunk())` will return everything your thunk will return) use a `ref` or do something like `store.getState` before continuing